# No se puede cargar el tipo 'xxx.Class1' del ensamblado

Tags: php

No se que sucede.

No se puede cargar el tipo 'xxxx.Class1' del ensamblado'xxxx, Version=3.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.